# Convert GHC.Int.Int64 to Int

Tags: haskell

I am trying to generate a random lazy `ByteString` of the same length as a lazy `ByteString` that I already have.

So I take the length of the `ByteString` and feed it into `getEntropy` like so:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L
import qualified System.Entropy as SE

string :: L.ByteString
string = L.pack "Hello world!"

randomString :: IO L.ByteString
randomString = L.fromChunks . (:[]) <$> SE.getEntropy (L.length string)
```

(using `L.fromChunks . (:[])` to convert from a strict `ByteString` to a lazy one.)

The problem is that `SE.getEntropy` is of type `Int -> IO ByteString` while `L.length` is of type `L.ByteString -> GHC.Int.Int64`.

How can I convert an `Int64` to an `Int`?

Comment: First, make sure it will fit! On ar 64-bit machine it will; on a 32-bit machine you will need to do some research.

Comment: you can `unsafeCoerce` it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can turn any `Integral` type into another `Num` type using [`fromIntegral`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral):

```
fromInt64ToInt :: Int64 -> Int
fromInt64ToInt = fromIntegral
```

Answer (score 4):

`fromIntegral`

In GHCI:

```
let a = 6 :: GHC.Int.Int64
let f :: Int -> Int; f x = x;

--this will error
f a
--this succeeds
f (fromIntegral a)
```